# Convert unix time to local iso time format to set in htmk date time picker

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

So, I have a unix time as
endingTime= 1669060881
and then I do this to convert it into ISO format
this.edate = new Date(endingTime*1000).toISOString() ===>  2022-11-21T20:01:21.000Z

slicing it so that it can fir html local date input
this.edate = this.edate.slice(0, -8) ===>  2022-11-21T20:01

and then patch this value in my date time picker of form
this.userForm['endingTime']['controls'].patchValue(this.edate);

html

---> shows result as 21-11-22 and 8:01 as the time

when I put the time 1669060881 in here https://www.epochconverter.com/
you can see two times

GMT: Monday, November 21, 2022 8:01:21 PM
Your time zone: Tuesday, November 22, 2022 1:31:21 AM GMT+05:30

I need the iso conversiton in "Your time zone" time but currentt edate val is the GMT timezone

pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleString` instead of `toISOString`

[Date.toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

```js
const ms = 1669060881 * 1000
const dateTime = new Date(ms).toLocaleString()
console.log(dateTime)
```

Comment: I know this works but the intput for date-time only accepts date in this format "2022-11-21T20:01"..how do i send correcr date and time in this format

Answer (score 0):

Don't re-invent the wheel and use some popular and well tested library when working with dates. Like `zonedTimeToUtc` from [date-fns-tz](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-fns-tz).

```
 const dateTime = zonedTimeToUtc(ms, 'Your timezone')
```

Comment: it is not clear how, I want the output to be in this format  2014-06-25T10:00:00.000Z local time

Comment: @rawrstar Date object dosn't contain any timezone information. Basically it's plain number and has no relation to timezone. If your Date is in UTC, `formatInTimeZone` from library date-fns-tz library can be helpful. Or built-in `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.